# ssh from hyper-v host to linux guest does not work. Does work perfectly from other machines. How to fix?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ping, hyper-v

I have a **linux** guest with ssh enabled on a hyper-v **host**.

Depending on the assigned vSwitch (Default or External), I can ssh into linux from hyper-v host but not from other systems, or I cannot ssh into linux from hyper-v host but I can ssh from other systems. In both cases, linux can access the internet.

**host**'s IP address is 192.168.1.204. Other **test** machine's IP address is 192.168.1.7.

**Case 1:**
Linux on Default vSwitch, assigned address 172.23.174.5

- ping from **host** to **linux** - works
- ssh from **host** to **linux** - works (as the network 172.23.160/20 is directly connected to host by the Hyper-V setup)
- ping from **test** to **linux** - will not work, since it is on another subnet
- ssh from **test** to **linux** - will not work, since it is on another subnet
- ping from **linux** to 8.8.8.8 - works

**Case 2:**
Linux on External vSwitch, assigned address 192.168.1.214

- ping from **host** to **linux** - **works!!**
- ssh from **host** to **linux** - **"Connection refused"   <<<--- this is the culprit**
- ping from **test** to **linux** - works
- ssh from **test** to **linux** - works
- ping from **linux** to 8.8.8.8 - works

Obviously, I could go with Case 1 (NAT) and use port forwarding (netsh interface portproxy..) on the host. But I'd rather like to understand why Case 2 does not work. **Especially why ping from host to linux works, but ssh does not.**

Any idea why this does not work and how to fix this?

Dan

Comment: Are you sure sshd on Linux is actually _listening_ on this address? (Check with `ss -l sport = :22` or `netstat -ltn`.) Are you sure the Linux firewall isn't rejecting the connection? "Connection refused" is a pretty specific indication that the server explicitly replied with a RST to the connection attempt.

Comment: sshd is listening on 0.0.0.0:22. 
ssh is possible from 192.168.1.7 ("test") while it is not possible from 192.168.1.204 ("host"). 
also, there is no firewall active on linux.

Comment: Does the Linux system _receive_ the connection attempt packets? (Do you see them in tcpdump?)

Comment: No, tcpdump (running on linux) does not see the ssh connection attempts from host to linux. tcpdump shows the ssh traffice from any other machine on the net 192.168.1.0/24 to linux, though. 
That is why I think it's rather a hyper-v/vswitch issue, than a problem with the linux configuration.